# C# Chart - multiple curves but color gets overwritten

Tags: c#, winforms

So i'm displaying multiple curves in my chart. However, when i generate a random color, all the other curves will get this color too.

```
int fileIndex=0;
Random r = new Random();
foreach (var i in graphContainer)
{
    fileIndex++;
    var series = new Series
    {
        Name                = legendNames[fileIndex],
        Color               = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(0, 256), r.Next(0, 256), r.Next(0, 256)),
        IsVisibleInLegend   = true,
        IsXValueIndexed     = false,
        ChartType           = SeriesChartType.Line
    };
    foreach (var j in i)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY (j.Item2, j.Item1);
    }
    chart.Invalidate        ();
    chart.Series.Add        (series);
}
```

Note: all the curves except one has the same values, but you get the idea.
[image]

Why is my curves getting the same colors?

Entire function:

```
    private void generateWaveformsFromFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fileIndex                       = -1;
        string folder                       = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\WaveForms\";
        string filter                       = "*.csv";
        string[] filePath                   = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filter);
        List<string> legendNames            = new List<string>();
        List<Tuple<double, double>> graph   = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
        List<List<Tuple<double, double>>> graphContainer = new List<List<Tuple<double, double>>>();
        chart.Series.Clear();
        foreach(var fileName in filePath) {
            legendNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
            {
                csvParser.SetDelimiters (new string[] { ";" });
                csvParser.ReadLine      ();
                while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fields     = csvParser.ReadFields();
                    double current      = Double.Parse(fields[0]);
                    double inductance   = Double.Parse(fields[1]);
                    graph.Add           (new Tuple<double,double>(current, inductance));
                }
                graphContainer.Add(graph);
            }
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        foreach (var i in graphContainer)
        {
            fileIndex++;
            var series = new Series
            {
                Name                = legendNames[fileIndex],
                Color               = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(0, 256), r.Next(0, 256), r.Next(0, 256)),
                IsVisibleInLegend   = true,
                IsXValueIndexed     = false,
                ChartType           = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            foreach (var j in i)
            {
                series.Points.AddXY (j.Item2, j.Item1);
            }
            chart.Invalidate        ();
            chart.Series.Add        (series);
        }
    }
```

Suggestion: (?)

[image]

Comment: is there only 1 "i", and it has all the points?  Are you using the same data to determine your legend?

Comment: graphcontainer appears to be a list of lists of tuple<,> and `IsVisibleInLegend` true in the series constructor would suggest that this is the source of the four different legend colors we actually see in the top right corner. strange. do you do anything to the legend once the series have been added?

Comment: @dlatikay Correct, graphContainer is of type `List<List<Tuple<double,double>>>`. No, i'm not doing anything else after this point to the graph. This is what displays the curves.

Comment: @Mike_G No, `i` is a `List<Tuple<double,double>>`, in graphContainer, ive stored all the different documents containing the graph-information.

Comment: @dlatikay I included the entire function for clarity.

Comment: @TaW What do you mean? How would i add + r.Next to the AddXY function?

Comment: Your curves do get different colors, now that the random error is corrected. You can see that in the Legend. But all seem to have the very same y-values. Add a ` + r.Next(0, 256)` to the AddXY call and you can see it.. The reason for that could be that you never reset the `graph` list, so it get longs but all graphContainer elements have (partially) the same data

Comment: I meant to add not just the y value but also a small random value. But now that the full code is there I think you can simply correct it by inserting a `graph() = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();` before the while loop to clear the old data..

Comment: @TaW This is what showed if i added the R.next (see updated)

Comment: LOL. So you see that all colors are present :-) - Now remove it again and reset the lsit before each loop..

Comment: @TaW Just to clarify, you *do* mean the `foreach`loop, and not the `while`-loop ? Not sure what you exactly want me to do here. graph()?

Comment: Before `while (!csvParser.EndOfData)`

Comment: @Taw Uhm, I appreciate your effort here but, graph() ? Where do you get graph() from? And how would that help? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174808/discussion-between-joel-and-taw).

Comment: @TaW Found the reason as to why clear() removed my charts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848659/2902996

Comment: No, this post doesn't explain the effect nor even deal with keeping several list instances in a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already posted one solution:

Before adding new data in a loop, make sure the old data are deleted. You do it by creating a new instance:

```
graph = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
```

This is a valid approach.

But for completeness' sake let's look at the more direct aproach as well:

```
graph.Clear();
```

This clears the data from the list object. But you are adding the graph to the `graphContainer` list like this:

```
graphContainer.Add(graph);
```

which means that **the very object** gets put into the list which, before the next loop, **will be cleared**. This is a common mistake. The solution is simple: Don't add the graph object itself into the  `graphContainer` list but a **copy** of it :

```
graphContainer.Add(graph.ToList());
```

The `ToList()` call is a simple way to create a copy of a `List<T>`.

---

As for the [post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848659/2902996): The old post is strictly about runtime performance. And not about creating copies of the lists.

But even there, the recommended way to do it is depending on whether you can predict the number of elements you will put in each list.

**If** you can predict it and **if** it is somewhat largish, let's say more than a few hundred of large **or** a many thousands of smallish elements you should tell the list which capacity it should reserve.

This avoids multiple growing pains. After a `Clear()` the `Capacity` is retained, avoiding new allocations.

Your elements (Tuples) are small, so you probably don't need to worry about the list growing performance..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user @Taw, i forgot to create a new instance of the `graph` or empty it, between runs.

```
graph = new List<Tuple<double, double>>(); // <-- solved it
while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
{
      string[] fields     = csvParser.ReadFields();
      ...
}
```

EDIT:

Do not use `yourList.Clear()` see here why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848659/2902996

Comment: No, this imo is a misunderstanding. You can and maybe should use the combination of `graph.Clear()` and `graphContainer.Add(graph.ToList());` It surely is a very good way to go. - The old post was only about runtime performance without any consideration of keeping various the list data in memory.- The being said, it may of may not matter how many data entries you expect when initializing the list. but since you want to put them in a chart they ought to be too large anyway..

Comment: I have added an answer after all, since yours didn't quite get all aspects right..